# Does QTP support Visual Foxpro applications?

Tags: automation, qtp

Does QTP support Visual Foxpro applications? I have to automate a Foxpro application. Which automation tool should I use?

- QTP
- Selenium
- Test Complete
- Ranorex
- Autoit
- Watir
- Skilltest

Comment: You know that visual foxpro is end of life since a few years?

Comment: Question 1: "Does QTP support Visual Foxpro application ? " -- no. Or well depends on what you mean with "support". Question 2: Which tool should you use -- Depends. Open a second question for that, preferably on "software recommendations", not here on SO.